# How do you form a finite vector space in a finite field?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to provide an example of a finite vector space $V$ over a finite field $F$ such that $V = V_1 \cup V_2 \cup V_3 \cup V_4 \cup V_5$ where the $V_k$ are proper subspaces.

Comment: What have you tried? Any thoughts? Do the $V_k$ have to be distinct?

Comment: Do you really mean the _union_? And do you have any good reason to think such an example exists?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes David! And the "good reason" is that the base field is finite.

Comment: @Menezio I don't see how the base field being finite helps. If we were just talking about $V=V_1\cup V_2$ you could still say the base field is finite, but in fact it's easy to see that $V=V_1\cup V_2$ is impossible.

Comment: Well obviously there is going to be a zero vector but Im not sure how to give an example for that field @runway44

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Take $(\mathbb F_2)^2$ and take the union of all the lines here.

Comment: @Menezio Thanks. Yes, it's obvious that you can do it for some number of subspaces since the field is finite, and to get $5$ we just need to count. Very good

Comment: @Menezio ??? I can't imagine what you feel the need to apologize for here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the vector space $(\mathbb F_2)^3$. Here take the five subspaces:
\begin{gather}
V_1 = \{x=0\}\\
V_2 = \{y=0\}\\
V_3 = \{z=0\}\\
V_4 = \{x=y, y=z\}\\
V_5 = \{x=y=0\}
\end{gather}

Essentially $V_1,V_2,V_3$ are coordinate hyperplanes of $(\mathbb F_2)^3$ and they contained all the points except for $P=(1,1,1)$ which is contained in $V_4$ that is the line connecting the origin with $P$.

The last subspace, $V_5$, is not necessary to complete all the space $(\mathbb F_2)^3$. I wrote down another subspace, distinct from the others, in order to have $5$ distinct subspace.

---

Edit: As Saulspatz suggested in comment, we can find $5$ distinct subspaces, where no $4$ of which cover the space. Just take a plane and the line through each of the $4$ points not in the plane.

Comment: Well, $V_1,V_2,V_3$ are the *coordinate* hyperplanes.

Comment: Right! I edited, thanks

Comment: To get $5$ distinct subspaces, no $4$ of which cover the space, take a plane, and the line through each of the $4$ points not in the plane.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks, I edited with your suggestion

Comment: so would an example of the vectors be V_1 = (0,1,1) V_2 = (1,0,1) V_3=(1,1,0) V_4 = (1,1,1) and V_5 = (0,0,0) (because there needs to be a zero vector)

Comment: @Kelly $V_k$ is a subspace so $V_k$ contains more than one vector. For example $V_1=\{x=0\} = \{(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (0,1,1)\}$ contains $4$ vectors. Try to write explicity all the elements of each subsbace; You will find that all the vectors of $(\mathbb F_2)^3$ lies in one of $V_k$.

Comment: wouldnt the vectors from the subspaces overlap in some places?

Comment: @Kelly Yes it's correct. But, as subspace, $V_i\neq V_j$ for all $i\neq j$. For example $V_1\neq V_2$ because the vector $(0,1,1)$ lies in $V_1$ but not in $V_2$.

Comment: so when i listed them out, i got V_1 = {(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(0,1,1)}  & V_2 = {(0,0,0), (0,0,1)(1,0,0),(1,0,1)} &  V_3 = {(0,0,0), (1,0,0)(0,1,0),(1,1,0)} &  V_4 = {(0,0,0), (1,1,1)} &  V_5 = {(0,0,0), (0,0,1)}

Comment: @Kelly Yes, it is correct. And now you can see that every vector of $(\mathbb F_2)^3 = V$ lies in one of the $V_i$; Hence $V_1\cup V_2\cup V_3\cup V_4\cup V_5 = V$.

Comment: ohhhh okay, Thank you so much!!